# Change constructor template in Eclipse so it calls setter(s)

Tags: java, eclipse, constructor, setter

For a sample Rectangle class, the auto-generated constructor in Eclipse using code templates is,

```
public Rectangle (double width, double side) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}
```

However, assuming setters have been created, I'd like it to be (without having to change it myself)

```
public Rectangle (double width, double side) {
    setWidth(width);
    setHeight(height);
}
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: Change the auto generated one to use setters?

Comment: Try deleting the setters then do a quickfix create getters and setters for all variables and it should change them...

Comment: You may have a look at this - http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2011/08/useful-eclipse-templates-for-faster.html

Comment: And also this stack overflow questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520480/modify-eclipses-default-constructor-template

Answer (score 1):

Calling an ovevrridable method from constructor is an anti-pattern and that is why eclipse does not support it. Reason being the superclass constructor runs before the subclass constructor, so the overriding method in the subclass will be invoked before the subclass constructor has run. If the overriding method depends on any initialization performed by the subclass constructor, the method will not behave as expected.